# How to center keyframe animation?

Tags: css

I have a keyframe animation using CSS, and I would like to (automatically) make it centered for all resolutions, browsers, etc. I've tried doing margin: auto, etc. But that always results in my animation not working. Perhaps I am inserting it incorrectly, but I don't know. This is what I currently have, without any auto margins.
Here is my CSS code:

```
#image {
    text-align:center;
    width:276px;
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%; 
    margin-left: -130px; /*this is what works for me, I'd imagine it's not */
    margin-top: -240px;  /*centered for everyone */
    animation:dampe 0.3s infinite; 
    -webkit-animation:dampe 0.3s infinite; 
}
@keyframes image {
0% { top:45%; }
50% { top:50%; }
100% { top:45%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes image {
0% { top:45%; }
50% { top:50%; }
100% { top:45%; }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="image.png" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HmUkA/

Answer (score 0):

By aligning the element using the margin-left property and offsetting by a fixed px value like in Joseph's solution you will not achieve a centered effect on all resolutions.

To achieve the centered effect on all resolutions offset your element by 50% from the left side and afterwards set the transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0). This will ensure that your element is always centered on the X axis, no matter the screen size.

```
/*CSS Markup*/
.centerX{
left:50%; 
-webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0);
}
```